# Have a bootstrap table's cell fill available area, scrolling on overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

So there are many questions regarding Bootstrap and Tables and responsiveness, but all the ones I've found seem to only deal with the *Table* scrolling or filling available area.

I'm having trouble getting a particular *cell* (`<td>` element) to
(a) fill to the available space, stopping at the window boundaries (eg: be fluid) and
(b) add horizontal scrollbars iff the cell would be too large.

### Goal:

[image]

### Best Effort

Here's what I've got so far. Things to note:

- I'm not using any custom CSS, just that provided by Bootstrap 4.1.3
- You'll see the `<div class="table-responsive">` is commented out - this is because I don't want the *entire table* to be scrollable.
- The `<pre class="pre-scollable">` part successfully adds the *vertical* scrollbar when the log has many lines, but it does not add a horizontal scrollbar
- I've tried wrapping the `results-log` cell in a bootstrap `class="container-fluid"` div, but that didn't really do anything.
- If I use `<pre class="pre-scollable" style="width: 250px; overflow-x: scroll">` I can get the horizontal scroll bar, but then it's no longer responsive.

  - Using different `width: inherit` doesn't work either.
- The whole thing is wrapped in a `<main class="container-fluid-page">` and another div, but I don't think that should have any effect... right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<!-- other stuff that doesn't matter -->
<main class="container-fluid-page">
<div id="content">

   <div id="results">
   <h2>Results:</h2>
   <!--<div class="table-responsive">-->
      <table class="table table-sm">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>Status</th>
               <td>
                  <div id="results-status">
                     foo
                  </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>ReturnValue</th>
               <td>
                  <div id="results-return-value">
                     <pre><code class="json">{
  "__type__": "RecordRef",
  "name": "foo"
}</code></pre>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>ReturnValue</th>
               <td>
                  <div id="results-log">
                     <pre class="pre-scollable"><code>2019-05-23 07:51:32Z Log text
2019-05-23 07:51:33Z log text that can have a really really really long line in it and I want to scroll
2019-05-23 07:51:34Z log text</code></pre>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <!--</div>--> <!-- class="table-responsive" -->
   </div> <!-- id=results -->

</div> <!-- id=content -->

</main>
</body>
```

### Edits:

1. Removed `col-*` from `<th>` and `<td>` definitions.

Comment: First of all, you can't use `col-*` for `<td>`s or `<th>`s in Bootstrap 4, because the grid system is based on `display:flex`. If you apply `display-flex` to your table elements, you shouldn't expect it to act like a table anymore. So you have to make a choice: either use grid system for layout (it appears the right choice in your case, since you don't actually display tabular data - think totals, sums, reordering elements, etc) or if you want to use a table (in which case you want to specify widths for your columns via CSS).

Comment: Ah thanks. It's been a while since I worked on this project and I *think* that the `col-*` were holdovers from when I switched away from using flexbox/grid. I've removed them from the example. No change of course, but you're right it could have caused other issues.

Comment: And secondly, you need at least to specify a `min-height` for your scrollable thingy. Without it, the browser can't figure out ***where*** you want to draw the line. When should it start scrolling? Same goes for the width of the first column. You have to tell the browser what's the minimal space for it. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/g5du4n8o/).

Comment: As for the *why* of changing from grid to table... I don't remember, haha. I'll look into switching back though, thanks.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the `pre-scrollable` class from Bootstrap takes care of that. [source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/code/#code-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Consideration

IMHO, you shouldn't have edited your question based on my comment. In doing so, you've made the question (far) less helpful for future users who might ask the same question:

> *"Why not use `col-*`s on table cells?*"

, which is a good question, considering Bootstrap's flexibility and versatility.

For future reference, here's the initial code of the question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<!-- other stuff that doesn't matter -->
<main class="container-fluid-page">
<div id="content">

   <div id="results">
   <h2>Results:</h2>
   <!--<div class="table-responsive">-->
      <table class="table table-sm">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th class="col-2">Status</th>
               <td class="col-10">
                  <div id="results-status">
                     foo
                  </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th class="col-2">ReturnValue</th>
               <td class="col-10">
                  <div id="results-return-value">
                     <pre><code class="json">{
  "__type__": "RecordRef",
  "name": "foo"
}</code></pre>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th class="col-2">ReturnValue</th>
               <td class="col-10">
                  <div id="results-log">
                     <pre class="pre-scollable"><code>2019-05-23 07:51:32Z Log text
2019-05-23 07:51:33Z log text that can have a really really really long line in it and I want to scroll
2019-05-23 07:51:34Z log text</code></pre>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <!--</div>--> <!-- class="table-responsive" -->
   </div> <!-- id=results -->

</div> <!-- id=content -->

</main>
</body>
```

---

### Answer

The reason why `col-*` classes can't be used on table cells is because, unlike in previous versions, starting from v4, Bootstrap uses `display:flex` and `flex-basis` for sizing grid layout, to allow for smart layout-ing techniques, such as equal distribution of positive or negative space, vertical & horizontal alignment and all the other goodies flexbox comes packed with (i.e: `order`).

For your case, I recommend using Bootstrap's native grid layout system as is:

```css
pre.pre-scrollable {
  max-height: 132px;
}

#results pre {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#results>.row>[class^="col-"] {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<main class="container-fluid" id="results">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <label>Status</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10" class="results-status">
      foo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label>Log</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10" class="results-log">
      <pre><code class="json">{
  "__type__": "RecordRef",
  "name": "foo"
}</code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label>Return Value</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10" class="results-return-value">
      <pre class="pre-scrollable"><code>2019-05-23 07:51:32Z Log text
2019-05-23 07:51:33Z log text that can have a really really really long line in it and I want to scroll
2019-05-23 07:51:34Z log text
2019-05-23 07:51:32Z Log text
2019-05-23 07:51:33Z log text that can have a really really really long line in it and I want to scroll
2019-05-23 07:51:34Z log text
2019-05-23 07:51:32Z Log text
2019-05-23 07:51:33Z log text that can have a really really really long line in it and I want to scroll
2019-05-23 07:51:34Z log text
2019-05-23 07:51:32Z Log text
2019-05-23 07:51:33Z log text that can have a really really really long line in it and I want to scroll
2019-05-23 07:51:34Z log text</code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Notice it handles responsiveness gracefully.
Removing the `-sm` compositor from the column class names will cause the columns to remain side by side on narrow screens (like a table would).

Comment: I agree that the question **"Why not use col-*s on table cells?"** and your answer to is is helpful for others. However, it's completely unrelated to my original question of **"How to get a single cell in a table to have XY scrollbars?"** That said, the recommendation of moving to grid layout is the correct solution for my use case, though it still doesn't answer the original question (which I admit is an XY problem).

Comment: @dthor, as you know, I already provided a practical answer to problem X [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/g5du4n8o/). Note I just updated it jwith a lengthy comment in the JS panel on why i used that technique. I've tried other ways of achieving the same result but each has its drawbacks and none was satisfactory, IMHO. Hope it helps understanding why X is a difficult problem to solve.